# Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $ such that $f(x+iy)=x^3+3xy^2+i(y^3+3x^2y)$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $ such that

> $$f(x+iy)=x^3+3xy^2+i(y^3+3x^2y)$$

let $f'(z)$ be the derivative of $f(z)$ ,Then which of the following is true

> 1)$f'(1+i)$ exists  and $|f'(1+i)=3\sqrt5$
>
> $2).f $ is analytic at origin
>
> $3).f$ is not differbtiable at $i$
>
> $4).f$ is differentiable at $1$

I tried to solve the question by using CR equation ,
$$u_x=3x^2+3y^2$$  $$u_y=6xy$$
$$v_x=6xy$$  $$v_y=3y^2+3x^2$$

form above i get that  this is not analytic because $u_y \neq -v_x$ thus option $2$ and $4$ are not true further i am not getting how to check for $1$ and $3$ option

Please help

Please help

Comment: Note that $u_y=-v_x$ holds if and only if $x=0$ or $y=0$.  Therefore, $f$ is complex-differentiable along the real and the imaginary axes, and nowhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions of the Cauchy-Riemann equations are the numbers $x+yi$ such that $x=0$ or $y=0$. Therefore, the correct options is the fourth one. The other options are wrong.

Comment: but if function is not analytic at point then it can't be differentiable at that point

Comment: How do you define analytic function?

Comment: a function is analytic at a point if itis differentiable at all the points in some neighbourhood  of that point

Comment: And with that definition, if $f$ is differentiable at some point $z_0$, it may well not be analytic, since it may well happen (as it does happen in this problem) that there is no neighbourhood $N$ of $z_0$ such that $f$ is differentiable at every point of $N$.

Comment: can you please elaborate this because now i am totally confused in this defination please help.

Comment: Take $f(z)=\lvert z\rvert^2=z\times\overline z$. It is easy to see that it is differentiable at $0$. But it is differentiable **only** at $0$. So, there is no neighbourhood of $0$ such that $f$ is differentiable at *all* points of that neighborhood. So, $f$ is *not* analytic at $0$.

Comment: If a function is differentiable at a point implies that it satisfies the Cauchy Riemann equation at that point , i use the contrapositive of this that if it is not satisfies the Cauchy Riemann equation  at point then it is not differntiable at that point.

Comment: Indeed. And... ?

Comment: ohhh i got it ,i was making a big mistake i was considering $1$ ans one but not $1+ i0$ form according to which it satisfies the Cauchy  Riemann equation hence it id differantiable at $1$ , am i right now?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: +1 ,thankyou sir

Comment: one thing more , the defination in my 3rd comment is good to define the analyticity ? or you would like to add something in that defination :-)

Comment: It is fine, although I think that this definition is better: $f\colon D\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ is analytic if, for each $z_0\in D$, there is some $r>0$ and some power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$ such that $D_r(z_0)\subset G$ and that$$\bigl(\forall z\in D_r(z_0)\bigr):f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n.$$